# Why is Python automatically removing negative values from image array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, convolution

I am trying to apply the below convolve method below on the cameraman image. The kernel applied to the image is a 3x3 filter populated with -1/9. I print the values of the cameraman image before applying the convolve method, and all I get are positive values. Next, when I apply the 3x3 negative kernel on the Image, I still get positive values when I print the values of the cameraman image after convolution.

The convolving function:

```
def convolve2d(image, kernel):
    # This function which takes an image and a kernel 
    # and returns the convolution of them
    # Args:
    #   image: a numpy array of size [image_height, image_width].
    #   kernel: a numpy array of size [kernel_height, kernel_width].
    # Returns:
    #   a numpy array of size [image_height, image_width] (convolution output).


    output = np.zeros_like(image)            # convolution output
    # Add zero padding to the input image
    padding = int(len(kernel)/2)
    image_padded=np.pad(image,((padding,padding),(padding,padding)),'constant')
    for x in range(image.shape[1]):     # Loop over every pixel of the image
        for y in range(image.shape[0]):
            # element-wise multiplication of the kernel and the image
            output[y,x]=(kernel*image_padded[y:y+3,x:x+3]).sum()        
    return output
```

And here is the filter I am applying to the image:

```
filter2= [[-1/9,-1/9,-1/9],[-1/9,-1/9,-1/9],[-1/9,-1/9,-1/9]]
```

Finally, these are the intial values of the images, and the values after convolution respectively:

```
[[156 159 158 ... 151 152 152]
 [160 154 157 ... 154 155 153]
 [156 159 158 ... 151 152 152]
 ...
 [114 132 123 ... 135 137 114]
 [121 126 130 ... 133 130 113]
 [121 126 130 ... 133 130 113]]
```

After convolution:

```
[[187 152 152 ... 154 155 188]
 [152  99  99 ... 104 104 155]
 [152  99 100 ... 103 103 154]
 ...
 [175 133 131 ... 127 130 174]
 [174 132 124 ... 125 130 175]
 [202 173 164 ... 172 173 202]]
```

This is how I call the convolve2d method:

```
convolved_camManImage= convolve2d(camManImage,filter2)
```

Comment: What's the type of your image array? Could it be unsigned?

Comment: In the numpy documentation for pad, I see no mention of negative values. I suspect behind the scenes there's an unsigned container somewhere.

Comment: I am using numpy array: `np.array(image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by how `numpy` `dtype`s work. As `numpy.zeros_like`'s help says:

> Return an array of zeros with the same shape and type as a given
>   array.

Thus your `output` might be dtype `uint8`, which use modulo arithmetics. To check if this is case add `print(output.dtype)` immediately after `output = np.zeros_like(image)` line

Comment: Can I use `np.zeros()` instead?

Comment: Well, using  `output = np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1]))` , instead of  `output = np.zeros_like(image)`  worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: I am glad to help you, but want to note `output = np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1]))` might be replace by more succint line: `output = np.zeros(image.shape[:2])`